# Trying to fetch multiple images from database but getting only first image multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am trying to fetch multiple images from MySQL database using PHP but instead of getting different images, I am getting the same image (i.e the first image) multiple times. Here's my code:

```
<?php
   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category")or die(mysql_error());
   $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
   for($i=0;$i<$result;$i++)
   {  
     $cat_id=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_id');
     $cat=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_name');
     $category_icon=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_icon');
     echo $cat_id;
     echo $cat . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($num_cat['category_icon']) . '" width="290" height="290">' ;
   }
?>
```

Comment: you need to loop over the result..

Comment: `$num_cat` what is it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the value of `$result` is not a number.

Try to change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_num_rows`:

```
<?php
   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category")or die(mysql_error());
   $result=mysql_num_rows($sql);
   for($i=0;$i<$result;$i++)
   {  
     $cat_id=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_id');
     $cat=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_name');
     $category_icon=mysql_result($get_cat,$i,'category_icon');
     echo $cat_id;
     echo $cat . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($num_cat['category_icon']) . '" width="290" height="290">' ;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this..

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['category_icon']) . '" width="290" height="290">' ;
}
```